Cycle-Sculpturing with Minimal Vertex-Deletion
given a simple, finite and symmetric graph $G(V,E)$ with $n$ vertices and at least $n$ edges
Question:

how can the smallest set of vertices $W\subset V$ be calculated for which the graph induced by $V\setminus W$ is connected and 2-regular, i.e. a single cycle.


Remark:
if we don't insist on a single cycle, we get a generalization of the maximal independent set ($MIS$) problem by means of the following generalized restatement of the

$MIS$ problem:
calculate the largest subset of the vertices whose induced  subgraph is $r$-regular when $r=0$

The solutions for arbitrary values of $r$ can then be stated as calculating the maximal regular independent subgraph ($max\, RISG$)
For $r=1$ we would have a maximal independent matching problem and for $r=2$ a relaxed version this question's problem

Ssince the graph is finite, the whole question is finite, and can be solved by exhaustive search. But perhaps you want something more computationally efficient. But then you run into the problem of determining whether $G$ is Hamiltonian, that is, has a cycle visiting every vertex, and that question is NP-complete.

@GerryMyerson Not sure Hamiltonicity arises here.  The only time we are looking at all nodes is when $W=\emptyset$, in which case it is easy to check whether the induced subgraph (which is the same as $G$) is a cycle.

@RobPratt Hamiltonicitx doesn't apply and if we remove none of the vertices, we do not necessarly have a connected 2-regular graph

@ManfredWeis I agree, and checking that is $O(n)$,

OK, I missed the bit about the "induced subgraph". My apologies.

In other words, you look for the longest induced cycle?

@FedorPetrov yes, that is the problem the question is aimed at.

This is the $r=2$ case of the maximum $r$-regular induced connected subgraph problem ($r$-MaxRICS), which is NP-hard for fixed $r$:
https://kyutech.repo.nii.ac.jp/record/2000071/files/E96.D_443.pdf

That's exactly what I was hoping for
